# Reading MD files in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, markdown

I'm developing a JavaFX application for cryptography where I aim to display cipher descriptions within tabs using Markdown content. Despite the existence of Markdown files in the specified directory, the application throws a FileNotFoundException. How can I resolve this issue? Additionally, any guidance on parsing Markdown effectively within JavaFX would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my folder structure:

```
Crypto_App
│
├── src
│   │── ClassicAlgoController.java
│   |── ClassicScene.fxml
    |───crypto_algos
        ├── ShiftCipher.md
        ├── AffineCipher.md
        ├── RailFenceCipher.md
        ├── VigenereCipher.md
        └── HillCipher.md
```

The Java methods:

```
@FXML
private TabPane tabPane;

@FXML
private Tab shiftCipherTab, hillCipherTab, affineCipherTab, railFenceCipherTab, vigenereCipherTab;

@FXML
    private void initialize() {
        String baseFolderPath = "Crypto_App/src/crypto_algos";
        loadMarkdownContent(shiftCipherTab, baseFolderPath + "ShiftCipher.md");
        loadMarkdownContent(affineCipherTab, baseFolderPath + "AffineCipher.md");
        loadMarkdownContent(railFenceCipherTab, baseFolderPath + "RailFenceCipher.md");
        loadMarkdownContent(vigenereCipherTab, baseFolderPath + "VigenereCipher.md");
        loadMarkdownContent(hillCipherTab, baseFolderPath + "HillCipher.md");
    }
    
    private void loadMarkdownContent(Tab tab, String filePath) {
        String markdownContent = readMarkdownFile(filePath);
    
        AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        webView.getEngine().loadContent(markdownContent);
        anchorPane.getChildren().add(webView);
    
        tab.setContent(anchorPane);
    }
    
    private String readMarkdownFile(String filePath) {
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                content.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content.toString();
    }
```

And here is the corresponding fxml file:

```
<TabPane layoutX="604.0" layoutY="20.0" prefHeight="727.0" prefWidth="748.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
        <tabs>
          <Tab fx:id="shiftCipherTab" text="Shift Cipher">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <AnchorPane layoutX="15.0" layoutY="15.0" prefHeight="668.0" prefWidth="718.0" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </Tab>
          <Tab fx:id="affineCipherTab" text="Affine Cipher">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
            </content>
          </Tab>
            <Tab fx:id="railFenceCipherTab" text="Rail Fence Cipher">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
               </content>
            </Tab>
            <Tab fx:id="vigenereCipherTab" text="Vigenere Cipher">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
               </content>
            </Tab>
            <Tab fx:id="hillCipherTab" text="Hill Cipher">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
               </content>
            </Tab>
        </tabs>
</TabPane>
```

Comment: How are you building your application? Are you using Maven or Gradle?

Comment: Your tree looks wrong. You should have a resources folder, into which (at root or otherwise) should be placed your markdown files. They should be loaded as resources too. So not *filePath* but `resourcePath` urls. Code: `return new String(getClass().getResourceAsStream(resourcePath).readAllBytes());`

Comment: @aled None, just a normal application with libraries referencing javafx-sdk

Comment: the path `"Crypto_App/src/crypto_algos" + "ShiftCipher.md"` results in `Crypto_App/src/crypto_algosShiftCipher.md"` that is not correct, missing separator  between last folder and file (same with others)

Comment: As others have suggested, usually it is best to follow the [Maven standard layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), even if you don't use Maven.  Though it is usually best to use a 3rd party build tool as well (Gradle or Maven).  Info on using JavaFX with such tools is at [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) and in your IDE documentation on build tool and JavaFX integration.  Using a standard layout and build tool is not required, but can have numerous advantages.

Comment: [Info in how to find resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other), which this question likely duplicates.  Also see the [eden JavaFX resources guide](https://edencoding.com/where-to-put-resource-files-in-javafx/).  Reading resources isn't something to specific to markdown, so I suggest if you have specific questions related to Markdown, that you ask them as new questions once your resource issues are resolved, keeping questions focused on one issue, rather than multiple.

Comment: @MohaSetif even if not using Maven/Gradle you are using some way to build, like command line commands, script files, some IDE build system.

Comment: @jewelsea But wait, does the getResource function look into the resources folder directly?

Comment: Questions like *”does the getResource function look into the resources folder directly”* really don’t make sense (or at least betray a massive misunderstanding of how Java works in general). The `resources` folder, like the `src` folder, is just a construct at development time. The `getResource()` method is executed at runtime (when else can anything get executed?). The `resource` folder doesn’t even exist when `getResource()` is executed. The `getResource()` method looks for a resource relative to the *classpath*.

Comment: The relationship between development folders (like `src` and `resources`) and what is on the class path when the application is running depends on how the application is built, which is typically either by a dedicated build tool (e.g. Maven or Gradle) or by your IDE. In the standard layout, `.java` files in the `src` are *compiled*, with the resulting `.class` files being placed on the class path in the build, and files in `resources` are *copied* to the build.

Comment: Details on where `getResources(…)` looks on the class path are described at length in the duplicate Q&A.